# Does the GC ever dispose of class members without the object itself being disposed?

Tags: c#

I'm taking over a project from someone that isn't a programmer and came across a lot of calls that set arrays to null with "free up memory" comments. Some of these calls were for local variables that get used at the start of a long method, but never touched again until that "freeing" call at the end. The rest of those are "globals" (actually class members of the windows form).

I know setting the local variables to null doesn't really help free up memory, but is it for the class members? The arrays in question are pretty large int arrays for storing data points of nc files (we need to make our own CNC post processor) and some of the arrays are used just for the initial processing procedure and then not used again until the user needs to process another set of files.

Is the GC able to recognize that those early arrays wont get used for a while and free up that memory even though they're class members of a Form still in use?

Comment: In theory it can, but the flow analysis for it is hard and I suspect most systems don't try.

Comment: Setting a local variable to null is detrimental, it prevents the GC from releasing their allocation at the earliest possible moment.  Very different story when they are fields of a form class, now their lifetime is tied to the life of the form.  Which tends to be up for a while, setting the field to null allows the GC to collect their referenced object.

Comment: @RaymondChen ok, so does setting the "global" arrays to null allow the GC to collect that memory then, since there is no longer any object reference the allocation?

Comment: @HansPassant ah ok. In some spots those member arrays are set to null, then are set to a new array (I'm assuming for resizing). Does the "new" keyword also release any memory the object was previously referencing?

Comment: No.  Maybe you shouldn't trust this programmer's code too much.

Comment: @HansPassant Setting to null doesn't prevent the compiler from realizing that the variable is dead earlier. FinnJ: The "new" keyword doesn't know where you're going to assign the memory to. The "made available to GC" happens when the compiler can prove that the old value is no longer used. Typically this is when a new value is assigned.